# Linux multithreading would involve the pthreads library(in most cases) . What is the equivalent library used by MSVC?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, multithreading

I need to know which are the APIs/library used for multithreading by MSVC . If there are more than one , please let me know which is the most widely used.

If my question sounds too naive , its because I've never done threading before , and from my past experience , I know there are people here who can get me started/point me at the right direction , from which point I can start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested you can use CreateThread or _beginthread or the threadpool APIs, [the process and threads reference is best](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Win32 threading, you can also use boost::thread which is very close to the C++0x std::thread standard.

The other option if you're using Visual Studio is to take a look at the Parallel Pattern Library and Asynchronous Agents Library which are part of Microsoft's [Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870(VS.100).aspx) (ConcRT) and are new in Visual Studio 2010. There are several how-to help topics which in the link that can help you get started here.

The API's in ConcRT are 'task' APIs rather than thread APIs and let you work at a slightly higher level of abstraction than threads. i.e. parallel loops, parallel pipelines and groups of tasks. Like boost::thread, the APIs are primarily setup to work with functors rather than the CreateThread / ThreadPool style APIs though there are APIs which are similar syntactically to CreateThread (Concurrency::Scheduler::ScheduleTask for example).

-Rick

Answer (score 4):

Threading on Windows doesn't require any extra library, it's built right into the Win32 API. For example, to create a thread, call [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx). The complete list of threading functions can be found on MSDN at [Process and Thread Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847(VS.85).aspx).

Note that if you are writing a program that uses MSVCRT, you may want to call the [`_beginthread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(VS.80).aspx) family of functions instead. Doing so will help set up and tear down additional data structures used to support threading by the MSVCRT library.

Comment: One more thing - the windows thread environment is preemptive , right ?

Comment: Well then , can u take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892104/can-a-thread-be-pre-empted-in-the-midst-of-a-system-call-to-kernel ? Can this scenario occur ( if not by default , made to occur ) on Windows ?

Comment: In Win7 x64 there is a new feature called User Mode Scheduled threads which will allow someone who's written a UMS Scheduler to receive notification when a blocking kernel call is made on a UMS thread and then schedule another UMS thread, this happens without a full context swap. ConcRT implements a UMS scheduler on Win7 x64, the 'event' how-to topic shows this.

Answer (score 2):

As @Greg said you can use CreateThread for creating  a thread on windows . Other option is to use boost threads which IMHO provide a much better interface for handling them.

Comment: And will also work on Linux and other platforms. And is almost identical to the threading model being added to C++0x. Definitely not a bad idea :)